# What are some mantras which are dedicated to Lord Indra?

Tags: scripture, vedas, rituals, mantras, indra

As we know that Lord Indra is the most important Vedic deity.

I want to ask if there is literature available for Lord Indra's worship. (except Vashitha Ganapati muni books)

Are there **mantras** (vedic/tantric/puranic) available for worship of **Lord Indra**?

Comment: First thing first, Indra is God (Deva), not Lord (Bhagwana).

Comment: @Rishabh didnt you read first line ?

Comment: @Rishabh who is bhagwana?

Comment: I have heard he is mentioned/praised most frequently in Vedas but "most important" seems kind of subjective. Is he called creator or source of universe in Vedas? If not then may be purusha of purusha suktas could be considered "most important"?  Anyway good question.

Comment: @Aks most important because he has highest number of suktas and mantras dedicated to him. highest number of vedic rituals dedicated to him. and cheif deity of yajnas. Now getting the reason?

Comment: @Rishabh Only Puranas say Indra is Deva. But vedas describe Indra as Brahman.

Comment: @the destroyer interesting.  I think I will ask a question on this if I can't find similar question.

Comment: @Aks Yes, Lord Indra is praised as the one who made these all worlds many times in RigVeda. For eg RigVeda 8.85.6 .. "Let us praise him who made these worlds and creatures, all things that after him sprang into being."... http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/rigveda/rv08085.htm

Comment: @TheDestroyer Indra has taken birth by Aditi. Whoever takes birth that can't become Parmatma. Parmatma/Bhagwan is the one who never takes birth and never dies. But Indra took birth and he is immortal only because of nectar. IN short He is not Parmatma (Lord).

Comment: @RakeshJoshi Yes, I did read first line But I also did read your heading/title line and last line of your also.

Comment: @Rishabh Rama was born to Kausalya. Does that make Lord Rama inferior?

Comment: @RakeshJoshi Bhagwan is the one who never takes birth and never dies. BUT Indra take birth by Aditi. And he drank nectar, only coz of nectar he can't be killed. But He came in existance in same way as we all came. Means by wish of Lord.

Comment: @Rishabh every one has fixed span until mahapralaya. from where you got this definition BTW?

Comment: @TheDestroyer Lord Rama is Lord Narayan Himself. He took birth by his own wish, Not by someone else's (Lord) wish like we all did (including Indra).

Comment: @TheDestroyer "Only Puranas say Indra is Deva." That is not true in the slightest.  There are countless Vedic passages describing Indra as a Deva. "But vedas describe Indra as Brahman." The Brahma Sutras describe exactly how to interpret statements which on the surface seem to say that Indra is Brahman.  This is something that all the commentators on the Brahma Sutras agree on.

Comment: @KeshavSrinivasan Brahma Sutras interpretation is accepted only by certain Hindus or Acharyas. If such statements are really superficial, then vedas themselves should say that.

Comment: Brahmasutra is nothing for vedics. only for vedantins . so its irrelevant here.

Comment: @TheDestroyer How to interpret such statements about Indra is something that Advaitins, Dvaitins, Visistadvaitins, etc. all agree on.

Comment: @RakeshJoshi By the way, every hymn in the Samhita of the Vedas consists of mantras, so are you asking for a list of all Vedic hymns addressed to Indra?  That would be a long list.

Comment: Not like that but specific mantras. which are used for anushthana.

Comment: **Im Indraya namaha** & **Aum Indrarajayaa Vidmahe Maha Indrayaa Dheemahi Tanno Indra Prachodayaat**, are two most dedicated mantras for lord Indra.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Here is an Agamic mantra (or Tantric mantra) dedicated to Lord Indra taken from the **Mantradeva Prakashika**.

> Im IndraYa Hrith | asya Brahmarishi Pangtischandaha Indro DevatA Im
>   Bijam Ayethi Shaktihi |
>
> .....
>
> **Im Indraya namaha**, for this mantra the Rishi is BrahmA, Chandah is
>   Pangti, Devata is Indra, Bija is Im, and Aya is the Shakti.

**Nyasa Vidhi:**

> Rishi Nyasa and KarAnga Nysas are done like - Sirasshi Brahmane
>   Rishayae namha...., Im Angushthabhyam namaha, Im Tarjanibhyam SwahA,
>   ...  Im ShikhAyai Vaushat, Im KavachAya Hum etc.

**DhyAnam:**

Dhyanam for Lord Indra for this particular mantra is to be done like this:

> Pitavarnam sahasrAksham Vajrapadmakaram Vibhum | Sarvalankarasamyuktam
>   Naumindram Dikpatiswaram ....||
>
> ........
>
> Indra Deva is having a yellowish body. He has thousand eyes. His one
>   hand holds his weapon, the vajra and in his other hand he holds a lotus.
>   Prostration to that Indra who is decked with varied and many ornaments
>   and who is the lord of directions.

Next to be done is the Shadanga Puja  which i am not giving the details of. Ayudha Puja (i.e Puja of the Vajra) is also to be done.

The purascharana of this mantra is done upon completing 1 lakh japa and doing 10 thousand homa with ghee mixed sesame seeds.

> **Asya Purascharanam Lakshyajapam**, Ajyena Tilairayuhomoho

**Prayoga:**

> Chatushkonasthapadme Navavastraveshtitam SthApayitvA Gandhodakena
>   Sampurya Tatra Tatra SaparivAramindramAradhya Sahsram JaptA
>   Tajjalobhishekam Brastarajasya RAjyaprAptiranyeshAm Parama
>   Srirbhavati...
>
> ...........
>
> In a square mandala an eight-petaled lotus is to be drawn. On that
>   lotus a kalash (pot) decked with the nine jewels is to be placed. The
>   kalash is then filled with gandha mixed water (sandal paste mixed with
>   water). Thereafter, Indra has to be invoked, along with his family, in
>   that pot and worshiped by doing a thousand japa of the mantra. Now the
>   devotee should bath in that water. This is called IndrAbhisheka. The
>   person on whom such an abhisheka is performed can even get back his
>   lost kingdom and gets many other priced belongings and etc.

Also  following is the gayatri mantra for Lord Indra [as given in the Linga Purana.](http://www.kamakoti.org/kamakoti/lingapurana/bookview.php?chapnum=26)

> Devaraajaaya vidmahey vajrahastaaya dhimahi, Tannah Shakrah
>   prachodayaat.

Comment: Thanks for this Rickross Ji So Gayatri Mantra of Indra can be chanted by Non Dvijas right? Why Tannah Shakrah ? Its Tannah Indra right ??

Comment: These mantras are given only to initiates? If no then how can Non Dvijas utter Puranic Mantras for worshipping Devas ??

Comment: Shakrah is another name of Indra. @SethuSrivatsaKoduru

Comment: Agamic mantras usually always require initiation. Puranic mantras can be chanted after one removes Om and Swaha etc. from them @SethuSrivatsaKoduru

Answer (score 9):

**`Are there mantras (vedic/tantric/puranic) available for worship of Lord Indra?`**

I found one Mantra in the Paushya Parva of [**Mahabhrata**](http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/m01/m01004.htm)   , **Which is hymn in praise of Indra -  Indra stuti (इन्द्र स्तुति). See P.41**. 
You can read  the story from above link.

> 150 तरीण्य अर्पितान्य अत्र शतानि मध्ये; षष्टिश च नित्यं चरति धरुवे
>   ऽसमिन
>       चक्रे चतुर्विंशतिपर्व यॊगे षड; यत कुमाराः परिवर्तयन्ति
>  151 तन्त्रं चेदं विश्वरूपं युवत्यौ; वयतस तन्तून सततं वर्तयन्त्यौ
>       कृष्णान सितांश चैव विवर्तयन्त्यौ; भूतान्य अजस्रं भुवनानि चैव
>  152 वज्रस्य भर्ता भुवनस्य गॊप्ता; वृत्रस्य हन्ता नमुचेर निहन्ता
>       कृष्णे वसानॊ वसने महात्मा; सत्यानृते यॊ विविनक्ति लॊके
>  153 यॊ वाजिनं गर्भम अपां पुराणं; वैश्वानरं वाहनम अभ्युपेतः
>       **नमः सदास्मै जगद ईश्वराय; लॊकत्रयेशाय पुरंदराय**
>
> trINy-arpitAn-yatra shatAni madhye ShaShTishcha nitya.n charati dhruve
>   .asmin .
>  chakre chatur-viMshati parva yoge ShaD yat-kumArAH
>   parivartayanti ..
>  tantra.n cheda.n vishvarUpaM yuvatyau
>   vayatas-tantUn-satata.n vartayantyau .
>  kR^iShNAnsitAMsh chaiva
>   vivartayantyau bhUtAnyajasraM bhuvanAni chaiva
>  vajrasya bhartA
>   bhuvanasya goptA vR^itrasya hantA namuchernihantA .
>  kR^iShNe
>   vasAno vasane mahAtmA satyAnR^ite yo vivinakti loke
>  yo vAjina.n
>   garbham-apAM purANaM vaishvAnara.n vAhanam-abhyupetaH .
>   **namaH sadAsmai jagadIshvarAya lokatrayeshAya purandarAya**
>
> Meaning - "This wheel whose circumference is marked by twenty-four
>   divisions representing as many lunar changes is furnished with three
>   hundred spokes! It is set in continual motion by six boys (the
>   seasons)! These damsels representing universal nature are weaving
>   without intermission a cloth with threads black and white, and thereby
>   ushering into existence the manifold worlds and the beings that
>   inhabit them! **Thou wielder of the thunder**, the protector of the
>   universe, the slayer of Vritra and Namuchi, thou illustrious one who
>   wearest the black cloth and displayest truth and untruth in the
>   universe, thou who ownest for thy carrier the horse which was received
>   from the depths of the ocean, and which is but another form of Agni
>   (the god of fire), **I bow to thee, thou supreme Lord, thou Lord of
>   the three worlds, O Purandara!'**

This is mantra uttered by Rushi  Utanka

> "The **Brahmana Rishi Utanka** having saluted the chief serpents in this
>   manner, obtained not, however, the ear-rings. And he thereupon became
>   very thoughtful. And when he saw that he obtained not the ear-rings
>   even though he had adored the serpents, he then looked about him and
>   beheld two women at a loom weaving a piece of cloth with a fine
>   shuttle; and in the loom were black and white threads. And he likewise
>   saw a wheel, with twelve spokes, turned by six boys. And he also saw a
>   man with **a handsome horse. And he began to address them the following
>   mantras:**

You can read Sanskrit shlokas here -[**Sanskrit**](http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/mbs/mbs01003.htm)

Comment: Along with hymns it will be better if you can add mantras

Comment: @RakeshJoshi - yes , i will also try to write it , but need a scriptural ref. i am looking for some other mantras also ,I  will  update the answer with mantra if found in authentic sourse.

Comment: yes i have upvoted. you can edit when you find more. Thanks

Answer (score 4):

There is a mantra for Indra to be found in the ancient Indian tradition of Natya-Shastra. Before any performance in the theater, it was customary to worship (*puja*) and offer certain food articles to the gods and deities. This ceremony was considered “as meritorious as a Vedic sacrifice”.

For Indra, the specific mantra runs as follows:

> पुरन्दरामरपते वज्रपाणे शतक्रतो ।
> प्रगृह्यतां बलिर्देव विधिमन्त्रपुरस्कृतः ॥
>
> purandarāmarapate vajrapāṇe śatakrato |
> pragṛhyatāṃ balirdeva vidhimantrapuraskṛtaḥ ||
>
> “O Purandara, the lord of gods, the thunder-bearer, the maker of the hundred exploits, accept this my offering consecrated by the Mantra.”
>
> Source: [Natya-shastra chapter 3](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/the-natyashastra/d/doc202359.html), also see [Indramantra](https://www.wisdomlib.org/definition/indramantra)

As for Vedic authenticity, in the first chapter it is said that Brahmā composed the Natyashastra from the four Vedas and it is called as the "fifth" Veda:

> The recitative (pāṭhya) he took from the Ṛgveda, the song from the Sāma[veda], the Histrionic Representation (abhinaya) from the Yajur[veda] and Sentiments (rasa) from the Atharvaveda, [and] thus was created the Nāṭyaveda connected with the Vedas principal and subsidiary (vedopaveda), by the holy Brahmā who is omniscient.
>
> Source: [Natya-shastra chapter 1](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/the-natyashastra/d/doc202329.html)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a mantra to Indra which may be what you're looking for:

> **Indra Gayatri Mantra:**
>   Aum Indrarajayaa Vidmahe
>   Maha Indrayaa Dheemahi
>   Tanno Indra Prachodayaat

From this YouTube video of it being chanted: [Sri Indra Dev Gayatri Mantra - श्री इंद्र देव गायत्री मंत्र – Powerful Mantra To Cure All Diseases - Dr.R.Thiagarajan](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GzFBZmciMUs)

Comment: Welcome! Answers on this site should be backed up with proper sources. Please visit [Guidelines for new users answering questions](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/q/125/3500)