# How are Indra and Saraswati related, when the bijakshara Aim - (ऐं) related to both?

Tags: mantras, indra, bijakshara

In spiritual realm bijaksharas have a vital place.  Many mantras carry bIjaksharas, apart from the deity's name.

For example:  chamunda mantra

“Om Aim Hreem Kleem Chamundaye Viche”

---

In general **Aim** bIjakshara is related to Saraswati.  In Rig Veda, [Saraswati Suktam](https://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/rigveda/rv06061.htm) appears, wherein Saraswati was eulogised as eliminator of majic spells and demons, as Indra did.

---

***aindra*** indicates that related to Indra.

As per this [answer](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/19049/3869),   the bijakshara *Aim* - (ऐं) related to Indra.

---

My doubt is

If aim (ऐं) is related to both Indra and Saraswati,  then how are Indra and Saraswati related  to each other?

Comment: in one word. no. bija mantras came through tantras.

Comment: Im is the Bija for Indra. Aim is well known to be the Bija for Saraswati. See this answer: https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/19049/4732

Comment: Thanks and up voted your other answer.  So using this bIja for both indra and Saraswati has roots in Rig Veda @Rickross

Comment: Can you write a answer correlating both the issues  @Rickross

Comment: I don't have anything else to write. I have to quote the same thing I have used in the other answer. So its not right to write the same things and get reps from it.@srimannarayanakv

Comment: BTW the Bijas are also mantras. So I have added the mantra tag here. @srimannarayanakv

Answer (score 1):

*Varsda Tantra*, Chapter 6:

> Aim
>
> Saravatyartha ai-sabdo binduhkhaharadhakah.
>
> SaravatyEi bijam etat tena Van im prapajayet.

This is bija for Sarasvati. The bija mantra and the Goddess are the same.

Comment: I know that Aim bija is for Saraswati.  Please read question again. I am expecting an answer in respect of correlating both Indra and Saraswati

Answer (score -1):

The seers of Rig Veda expressed their SPIRITUAL EXPERIENCES through mantras.  Those mantras were composed in a cryptic language.

Apart from eulogising the various aspects of the Almighty as Vishnu, Indra, Agni, etc, the union of Male and Female energies of the same Almighty was narrated as [Bliss of SOMA](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/36543/3869), in a subtle manner.

The eulogisation of the Almighty as the Female Power Saraswati can be found in [Saraswati Sukta](https://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/rigveda/rv06061.htm) (Rig Veda VI.61.

In this Sukta, the Saraswati was eulogised as eliminator of Paravatas, as Indra was eulogised as the eliminator of Vritra.  And, she was eulogised as destroyer of great deluder VRISAYA - बर्हय.

Further, in Rig Veda 6.61.5 and onwards, she was equalled with Indra, Pusan, Surya, etc.

---

So Saraswati, the ONE face of Almighty, is nothing but INDRA, another face of the Almighty.

So whatever applicable to Indra is applicable to Saraswati also.

The aim, which is related to Indra is related to Saraswati also.