# How to worship Indra?

Tags: worship, indra, yajna

How to worship Indra and what is the proper way to worship him, can he only be worshipped through yagna or shamanic ways are allowed ?

Comment: Can you elaborate what are Shramanic ways of worship? Lord Indra can be worshipped in Yajna, in regular worship while worshipping the Dikpalas (Om Indradi dasa dikpalebhyoh namaha etc.). He can be worshipped in a Yantra too (https://www.indiamart.com/proddetail/kesar-zems-copper-shri-indra-yantra-10-cm-x-10-cm-x-0-05-cm-copper-22098874155.html.) For mantras on Indra you may see this post: https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/19027/what-are-some-mantras-which-are-dedicated-to-lord-indra/19049#19049