# Where can i find a copy of Mantradeva Prakashika?

Tags: vedas, mantras, indra, tantra

[What are some mantras which are dedicated to Lord Indra?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/19027/what-are-some-mantras-which-are-dedicated-to-lord-indra) - @[Rickross](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/users/4732/rickross) ji's answer to this question piqued my interest in this book. I couldn't find a printed copy or a pdf copy anywhere. Where can i buy or get a copy of Mantradeva Prakashika? Kindly help me.